# Using a generic method pointer of a base class to call methods of derived classes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an event handling system where objects can subscribe to events broadcasted by other objects and call a method when that event is broadcast. I'm trying to implement this with a singleton class called `EventHandler`. Objects call a public method on `EventHandler` that subscribes them to events broadcast by a certain object:

```
void startWatchingObjectEvent(PDObject * object, PDEvent event, PDObject* listener, PDReceiver receiver);
```

`PDObject` is a base class for all the objects that will be handled by the `EventHandler`. `PDEvent` is simply a unique string that identifies the Event.

`PDReceiver` is where I'm running into issues. I have it typedef'd to a method pointer on the `PDObject` class:

```
typedef void (PDObject::*PDReceiver)(PDObject*, PDEvent);
```

Now the `PDObject` class itself doesn't really have any methods that `EventHandler` is going to call, but derived classes of `PDObject` will, and I wanted to create a generic type that `EventHandler` could store that would apply to any derived classes of `PDObject`. I implemented `EventHandler` this way and tried writing a unit test to make sure it's working okay:

```
const PDEvent Test_PokeEvent = "Test_PokeEvent";

void Test_EventHandler_sendObjectMessage()
{
    EventHandler& eventh = EventHandler::instance();
    Test_PDObject caster;
    Test_PDObject listener;
    PDReceiver receiver = &Test_PDObject::test_poke;
    eventh.startWatchingObjectEvent(&caster, Test_PokeEvent, &listener, (listener.*receiver)(&caster, Test_PokeEvent));
    eventh.sendObjectEvent(&caster, Test_PokeEvent);
    assert(listener.test_wasPoked());
}
```

`Test_PDObject` is a derived class of `PDObject` that just flips a `wasPoked` bit when `test_poke` is called.

The issue is that the compiler doesn't like me trying to assign a method of `Test_PDObject` to the type `PDReceiver` since `PDReceiver` is defined as a method of `PDObject`.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? Can I use this generic method pointer type to refer to methods of derived classes? Or is my approach just entirely flawed?

EDIT: I figured out I can use `static_cast` to cast the method pointer of the derived class to a method pointer of the base class like so:

```
PDReceiver receiver = static_cast<PDReceiver>(&Test_PDObject::test_poke);
```

And so far so good! My unit tests are working perfectly now.

Comment: You should not update the question with the answer, but instead either mark one of the posted answers as *accepted*, or answer your own question and mark that post as *accepted*.

Comment: Okay. I'm new here, so thanks for letting me know. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *static_cast* is indeed all that is required to cast a *pointer-to-member* of type `Child::*` to type `Base::*`, but please remember that this might be quite dangerous if you by accident use the *pointer-to-member* on an instance of `Base` (and not the related `Child`).

---

In the example below we use the same exact approach as described earlier, though calling `Child::func` on a object of type `Base` is causing *undefined-behavior* since we are accessing a *non-existent* member of Base inside the function.

```
struct Base {
  /* ... */
};

struct Child : Base {

  void func () {
    this->x = 123;
  }

  int x;
};
```

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  typedef void (Base::*BaseFuncPtr) (); 

  BaseFuncPtr ptr_to_child_func = static_cast<BaseFuncPtr> (&Child::func);

  Base b;

  (b.*ptr_to_child_func) (); /* undefined-behavior */
}
```