# Accessing a member function from another class without prior knowledge of the specific member function

Tags: c++, oop, function-pointers

I want to create a class that will access the member functions of a family of classes. Going into more detail, I have class ControlChaos which is declared like this:

```
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object, ptrToMember) ((object)->*(ptrToMember))

typedef double (MultiMaps::*mapsGetPtr)();
typedef void (MultiMaps::*mapsSetPtr)(double para);

class ControlChaos
{
public:
    ControlChaos(MultiMaps* _map,
                 mat orbitPoints,
                 colvec initCond,
                 mapsGetPtr getPtr,
                 mapsSetPtr setPtr,
                 double deltaMax,
                 double epsilonNeighborhood,
                 int controlIterations,
                 int maxIterations);

/* Other stuff here. */
};
```

with protected member variables which are of type mapsGetPtr and mapsSetPtr, and others. In the implementation, I use

```
 CALL_MEMBER_FN(map,setPtr)(someParameter);
```

to call the function which I specified using a function pointer in the constructor of ControlChaos. The member functions I want to access are members of classes derived from MultiMaps. This code, by itself, compiles fine. When I try to instantiate a ControlChaos object with a function pointer pointing to a member function in a class derived from MultiMaps, then the compiler complains that I gave it the wrong argument type.

Moreover, this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) seems to imply that a static cast could do the job, but I haven't found this to be true.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: I think I basically was having the same issue as you here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487361/using-a-generic-method-pointer-of-a-base-class-to-call-methods-of-derived-classe

`static_cast` ended up working for me, I just cast the derived method pointer to a base method pointer.

Comment: You might want to look up e.g. [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn), or if your compiler is C++11 capable [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *static_cast* is indeed all that is required to cast a *pointer-to-member* of type `Child::*` to type `Base::*`, see the following snippet:

```
struct ChildOfMultiMap : MultiMap { 
   ...
};

...

void(ChildOfMultiMap::* child_mem_ptr)(double) = &ChildOfMultiMap::set;

mapsSetPtr ptr = static_cast<mapsSetPtr> (child_mem_ptr);
```

<sup>*Please remember that this might be dangerous if you by accident use the *pointer-to-member* on an instance of `Base` (and not the related `Child`).*</sup>

---

#### In what way might this be dangerous?

In the snippet below we use the same exact approach as described earlier, though calling `Child::func` on a object of type `Base` is causing *undefined-behavior* since we are accessing a *non-existent* member of Base inside the function.

```
struct Base {
  /* ... */
};

struct Child : Base {

  void func () {
    this->x = 123;
  }

  int x;
};
```

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  typedef void (Base::*BaseFuncPtr) (); 

  BaseFuncPtr ptr_to_child_func = static_cast<BaseFuncPtr> (&Child::func);

  Base b;

  (b.*ptr_to_child_func) (); /* undefined-behavior */
}
```